# Sum custom post meta values

Tags: php, wordpress

This should be really straightforward..

I have a custom post type: "shipment" with a custom field "shipment_cost"

I want to sum the total cost of all shipments.

I've managed to get it to output the correct amount with a single post:

```
$totalcost = 0;
$post_ids = [2583];
foreach( $post_ids as $post_id )
{ 
    $totalcost += (int) get_post_meta( $post_id, 'shipment_cost', true );
}
echo $totalcost;
```

But when I try to use all shipment CPTs in an array, I get a result of zero.

```
$shipments = array(
'post_type'     => 'shipment'
);
$totalcost = 0;
$post_ids = $shipments;
foreach( $post_ids as $post_id )
{ 
    $totalcost += (int) get_post_meta( $post_id, 'shipment_cost', true );
}
echo $totalcost;
```

Is my shipments array wrong, or am I just going about this the wrong way in general?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it seems that you are using `$shipments` as it was an array of post ids? You first need to retrieve all post ids:

```
$shipments = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'shipment',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
));
```

Since the above would return post object you need to modify your loop:

```
foreach ($shipments as $post) {
  $totalcost += (int) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shipment_cost', true);
}
```

A better and faster way might be to use a raw database query to get the sum for all meta values:

```
$totalcost = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
                             INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
                             WHERE pm.meta_key = 'shipment_cost' 
                             AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
                             AND p.post_type = 'shipment'");
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the wp query route and it worked great. Just out of curiosity, why is a raw query better in this case? I'm very new to querying SQL and had ready that it was generally better to go with wp query as opposed to raw SQL queries. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. I just meant that it would be better to use a single query instead of making a request for every post.

Comment: Ah ok great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This just saved my life!! Been looking for a solution to total inputs from a Pods Custom Post Type which has a Custom Field that users can enter a number into. I then wrapped the code in a shortcode to display on front end

```
function jobs_shortcode () {
$jobs = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'pledged_job',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
));

$total = 0;
$post_ids = $jobs;

foreach ($jobs as $post) {
  $total += (int) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'jobs_pledged', true);
}

echo $total;
}   
add_shortcode( 'jobs', 'jobs_shortcode' );
```

THANK YOU!